# ggeffects::ggpredict() doesn't return population level prediction intervals for nlme::lme()

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, nlme, marginal-effects

I'm trying to get population level prediction intervals (PI) from `ggeffects:ggpredict()` using `type = "re"` from an `nlme:lme()` model. ggpredict is not returning the expected data for the lme() model, while the equivalent lmer() model works fine. My data are autocorrelated repeated measures, so I need lme() with `correlation = corAR1()`.

I'm not sure if this is an error, or if I'm just trying to do something for which the tools I'm using aren't designed?

```
library(lme4)
library(nlme)
library(ggeffects)

Data <- data.frame(
  Subject = factor(c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
                     4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                     5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
                     6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
                     7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
                     8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
                     9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
                     13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
                     14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
                     19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19)), 
  x = c(20.0, 28.5, 38.0, 47.5, 57.0, 66.5, 76.0, 85.5, 95.0, 100.0, 
           21.0, 31.5, 42.0, 53.0, 63.0, 73.5, 84.0, 95.0, 100.0, 
           20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 100.0, 
           22.0, 33.0, 44.0, 56.0, 67.0, 78.0, 89.0, 100.0, 
           21.5, 32.0, 43.0, 54.0, 65.0, 76.0, 86.5, 100.0, 
           20.0, 29.0, 38.5, 48.5, 58.0, 67.5, 77.0, 87.0, 96.5, 100.0, 
           23.0, 33.0, 44.0, 56.0, 67.0, 78.0, 89.0, 100.0, 
           23.5, 34.5, 46.5, 57.5, 69.5, 80.5, 92.5, 100.0, 
           20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 100.0, 
           25.0, 37.5, 50.0, 62.5, 75.0, 87.5, 100.0)/100,
  y = c(1.10, 1.00, 1.25, 1.60, 1.40, 1.20, 2.50, 4.60, 6.80, 10.40, 
          0.90, 1.00, 0.75, 0.90, 1.10, 1.70, 4.35, 9.95, 11.45, 
          1.20, 0.70, 1.30, 1.40, 0.70, 1.25, 2.30, 4.30, 8.20, 
          1.55, 1.15, 0.95, 1.10, 1.90, 3.25, 7.20, 14.30, 
          1.85, 2.00, 1.70, 2.00, 2.35, 3.30, 7.30, 12.10, 
          2.20, 1.95, 1.15, 1.55, 1.65, 3.00, 4.45, 9.05, 13.75, 15.85, 
          1.55, 1.20, 1.35, 1.60, 1.65, 4.70, 6.45, 10.80, 
          1.00, 0.90, 1.00, 1.10, 1.60, 3.60, 8.05, 12.30, 
          0.85, 1.00, 1.05, 1.00, 1.35, 2.00, 3.65, 6.75, 13.10, 
          2.25, 2.35, 2.40, 2.80, 4.90, 8.15, 13.50)
)

Model.lme4 <- lmer(
  y ~ x + (1 | Subject),
  data = Data
)

# first running lme() without autocorrelation
Model.nlme <- lme(
  fixed = y ~ x,
  random = ~ 1 | Subject, 
  data = Data,
)

# Expected data return fine from the lmer() model:
ggpredict(
  Model.lme4,
  terms = c("x [all]"),
  type = "re",
)
# Predicted values of y
# 
#    x | Predicted |         95% CI
# ---------------------------------
# 0.20 |     -1.09 | [-5.93,  3.74]
# 0.28 |     -0.08 | [-4.89,  4.73]
# 0.38 |      0.99 | [-3.80,  5.78]
# 0.47 |      2.06 | [-2.71,  6.84]
# 0.58 |      3.38 | [-1.39,  8.14]
# 0.67 |      4.51 | [-0.26,  9.28]
# 0.77 |      5.70 | [ 0.92, 10.48]
# 1.00 |      8.44 | [ 3.61, 13.27]
# 
# Adjusted for:
# * Subject = 0 (population-level)
# 
# Intervals are prediction intervals.

# When run on the lme() model, predicted values & PIs are missing:
ggpredict(
  Model.nlme,
  terms = c("x [all]"),
  type = "re",
)
# Predicted values of y
# 
#    x
# ----
# 0.20
# 0.28
# 0.38
# 0.47
# 0.58
# 0.67
# 0.77
# 1.00
# 
# Adjusted for:
# * Subject = 0 (population-level)
# 
# Intervals are prediction intervals.
```

If I use `correlation = corAR1()` it produces the same results as above.
The same thing also happens if I explicitly call `terms = c("x [all]", "Subject [0]")`

When I add the intended autocorrelation structure, I get prediction & PI values, but only for the first level of the `Subject` factor:

```
Model.nlme <- lme(
  fixed = y ~ x,
  random = ~ 1 | Subject, 
  correlation = corAR1(form = ~ x | Subject),
  data = Data,
)

ggpredict(
  Model.nlme,
  terms = c("x [all]"),
  type = "re",
)
# Predicted values of y
# 
#    x | Predicted |         95% CI
# ---------------------------------
# 0.20 |      1.64 | [-1.44,  4.71]
# 0.28 |      2.82 | [-0.23,  5.87]
# 0.38 |      4.07 | [ 1.03,  7.12]
# 0.47 |      5.33 | [ 2.29,  8.36]
# 0.58 |      6.86 | [ 3.82,  9.90]
# 0.67 |      8.18 | [ 5.13, 11.24]
# 0.77 |      9.58 | [ 6.50, 12.66]
# 1.00 |     12.78 | [ 9.61, 15.95]
# 
# Adjusted for:
# * Subject = 3
# 
# Intervals are prediction intervals.
```

Am I making an error somewhere? Or is there a better way to get the PIs that I want? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you might be stuck.

The underlying problem is that `broom.mixed::tidy` doesn't return the standard deviations of BLUPs:

```r
library(broom.mixed)
tidy(Model.lme4, effects = "ran_vals") ## includes SDs
tidy(Model.nlme, effects = "ran_vals") ## doesn't
```

However, this isn't really `broom.mixed`'s fault. The problem is that at present the `nlme` package doesn't offer any option to return the standard deviations of the BLUPs (see e.g. [this r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2009q1/001758.html), which discusses the issue but peters out without providing a solution).

In order to fix this, as best I can tell, you (or someone) would have to dig into the guts of `nlme` and figure out how to construct the SDs for the BLUPs. If I were doing it I would start with [Bates et al 2015](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf) equations 56-59 and see whether it's possible to extract the corresponding components from an `lme` fit. In particular see section 2.2 of Pinheiro and Bates 2000 for the notation and framework used in `nlme`: eq 2.22, p. 71, gives the expression for the BLUPs, hopefully one could match that up with the `lme` code *and* derive the corresponding expression for the SDs ...

**alternatively**: you can fit an AR1 model in `glmmTMB`, which should be `tidy`-able/`ggpredict`-able. Code is shown below; I think these are equivalent models, but the example data you've given above doesn't support fitting an AR1 model [we get a singular fit], so I can't be sure.

```r
## define a per-subject observation-number variable (factor)
## alt. tidyverse: Data |> group_by(Subject) |> mutate(obs = seq(n())) |>
##                  mutate(across(obs, factor))
Data2 <- (Data
    |> split(Data$Subject)
    |> lapply(FUN = \(x) transform(x, obs = seq(x)))
    |> do.call(what = rbind)
    |> transform(obs = factor(obs))
)
Model.nlme.acf <- update(Model.nlme,
                         data = Data2,
                         correlation = corAR1(form = ~obs))
library(glmmTMB)
Model.glmmTMB <-  glmmTMB(y ~ x + (1|Subject) + ar1(0 + obs|Subject),
                          data = Data2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will dig into those options. Regarding the singular fit, yeah this is just a subset of the original data. I'll try it on the full dataset.

Comment: So I'll have to do a lot more reading to wrap my head around `glmmTMB`, but I think this is a working solution. At least from a visual approximation, the glmmTMB polynomial fit on the whole dataset seems more appropriate compared to the equivalent `nlme` fit which returns PIs for only the first ```Subject```. https://i.imgur.com/9yQRosh.png Thanks for pointing me in the right, or at least a productive direction!

Comment: Couple follow up questions if you get a chance: is there any difference in this case between `ar1(0 + obs|Subject)` and `ar1(obs - 1|Subject)` as I've seen elsewhere? And why in the figure I commented does it seem like the glmmTMB PI is smaller at the far right where the between-subject variability is highest? I would expect the PI to be wider at that point?

Comment: Oh, maybe to hypothesise an answer to the second of my own questions: In this dataset every subject has an observation at 100% on the x-axis, while at all other x values the subjects are scattered at unique values. So is the higher effective n at 100% shrinking the standard error from which CI & PI are produced?

Comment: Answering the easy question: `0 + obs` and `obs -1` (or `-1 + obs`) are exactly equivalent.